# VBA SQL Error in insert

Tags: sql, vba, excel-2010

I have an error with my SQL insert statement. The error is

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

My SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO [table1] ('Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3') 
VALUES (2018-2019, Data2, Data3)
```

`Data2` and `Data3` are strings

Here is the code I used to generate my sql string

Just to try and get it working I replaced the variables with string litterals but I would like to move the variables back in.

I got several errors

First is expecting 3 paramaters
Second missing query operator

Calling Functionm I checked the data give me what I am looking for

```
createSQLforInsert tableName, pkData(0, 0), pkData(0, 1), FiscalYear

Public Function createSQLforInsert(tableName As String, dType As String, role 
As String, FiscalYear As String)
Dim SQL As String
Dim tempString As String
tableName = tableName & "$"
tempString = ""
'SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "] ([Fiscal Year], [Type], [role]) "
SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "] ([FiscalYear], [Type], [Role]) "
SQL = SQL & "VALUES ([" & FiscalYear & "], [" & dType & "], [" & role & "]) "

Debug.Print SQL

insertQuery SQL
End Function
```

Here is my current query

```
INSERT INTO [Data-People$] ([FiscalYear], [Type], [Role]) VALUES ([2018-2019], [RA], [Department Data])
```

This gives me an error expecting three parameters too few parameters.

Comment: Can you also show how are you calling the function? And where do you need `FiscalYear`, `role` and `dType`? These are not used in the function. Plus I guess that instead of `insertQuery SQL` the line should be `createSQLforInsert = SQL`?

Comment: insertSQL will execute the sql statement using ADO. I know that function works though so no issues there.

Comment: Really dirty way of doing it - change the first SQL to this one: `SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "] ([" & FiscalYear & "], [" & dType & "], [" & role & "]) "`, **IF** you have columns in the table named with the values that you are passing in `FiscalYear`, `dType` etc.

Comment: Sorry should of clarrified. The column headers are FiscalYear, Type, Role the variables are the data which should correspond to them

Comment: @CetinBasoz - considering that the OP is passing the column names as parameters and the name of the column is not "FiscalYear" but probably `2015` it would work.

Comment: @Vityata, no he is not. He messed it up all I know, but he wants to pass them as data.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - what if the value of the variable `FiscalYear` is the string "Fiscal Year"? It would work quite nicely.

Comment: I have updated the question please see above

Comment: @Vityata Fiscal Year is the actual data for what year I am inserting.

Comment: It should be: INSERT INTO [Data-People$] ([FiscalYear], [Type], [Role]) VALUES ('2018-2019', 'RA', 'Department Data')

Comment: Ok but how do I put single quotes in my function when creating the query?

Comment: @CetinBasoz I added the single quotes but still have the expecting three values error

Comment: Check my edited reply. You really should use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my other reply, use parameters, never attempt to create SQL statements like that concatenating strings.

```
Public Function createSQLforInsert(tableName As String, dType As String, role 
  As String, FiscalYear As String)
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim tempString As String
  tableName = tableName & "$"
  tempString = ""
  SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "] ([Fiscal Year], [Type], [role]) " & _
        " VALUES (@data1, @data2, @data3)"
  Debug.Print SQL

'insertQuery SQL
End Function
```

I commented out "insertQuery SQL" because its code is missing and you would need to pass @data1, 2 and 3's values to there if they are not constructed in that "insertQuery" method. This method does a very unnecessary thing IMHO and just build an INSERT statement. You could simply type this where it is needed.

EDIT: Anyway I am giving a sample with parameters:

```
    Public Function insertFiscalData(tableName As String, dType As String, role As String, FiscalYear As String)
      Dim SQL As String

      SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "$] ([Fiscal Year], [Type], [role]) " & _
            " VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)"

     Dim oConnection As ADODB.Connection
     Dim oCommand As ADODB.Command
     Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
     Set oCommand = New ADODB.Command

    oConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=... fill correct conn info here"

  oConnection.Open
  oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection
  oCommand.CommandText = SQL

  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@p1", adVarChar )
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@p2", adVarChar )
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@p3", adVarChar )

  oCommand.Parameters("@p1").Value = FiscalYear
  oCommand.Parameters("@p2").Value = dType
  oCommand.Parameters("@p3").Value = role

  oCommand.execute
  oConnection.Close

    End Function
```

Comment: I want to make a general function to build my insert statements so I don't have to construct everyone

Comment: Is this ADO? i will give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @User, Yes you would add Microsoft.ActivexDataObjects from references (I don't know your environment, but since this is VBA there should be some tools\references).

Answer (score 2):

Column names are not strings (2018-2019 you meant int -1):

```
INSERT INTO [table1] ([Row 1], [Row 2], [Row 3]) 
VALUES (2018-2019, @Data2, @Data3)
```

Data2 and Data3 should be passed as parameters.

If you meant you want to literally insert 'Data 2' and 'Data 3':

```
INSERT INTO [table1] ([Row 1], [Row 2], [Row 3]) 
VALUES (2018-2019, 'Data 2', 'Data 3')
```

Note: Do not put quotes around 2018-2019 if you didn't mean '2018-2019' string literal.

Comment: INSERT INTO [Table-1] ([Row  One], [Row  Two], [Row  Three]) VALUES(2018-2019, Data 2, Data 3)

Comment: Theres my new query but I have the same error. It is complaining about Data 3

Comment: @user, You mean your new syntax is in the comment above? It is worse. As I said you would pass data2 and 3 as parameters. Please edit your question and give your complete code. If you don't know how to use parameters I might edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Data2` and `Data3` are strings, then they should be passed with `'`:

```
CREATE TABLE table11 (
    [Row 1] varchar(255),
    [Row 2] varchar(255),
    [Row 3] varchar(255),
);

INSERT INTO table11 ([Row 1], [Row 2], [Row 3]) 
VALUES ('2018-2019', 'Data 2', 'Data 3')
```

[image]

**Note:** Lots of people would probably advise not to put space in the names of the columns. E.g. use CamelCase or "_".

---

Concerning putting the sql into VBA - the `'` should not be a problem:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO table11 ([Row 1], [Row 2], [Row 3]) " & _
                "VALUES ('2018-2019', 'Data 2', 'Data 3')"
    MsgBox sql
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a space in data as well as i am doing this in VBA. So how do i keep the single tick?

Comment: @User - what space in the data? What is a single tick?

Comment: VALUES ('2018-2019', 'Data2', 'Data3') is VALUES ('2018-2019', 'Data 2', 'Data 3')

Comment: As well -----> ' is a single quote and I am note sure how to include that in a string in VBA

Comment: @User, you would need double single quotes if you need quote in the string. BUT instead you simply would use parameters and simply input a single quote.

Comment: I am now having expecting three parameters when I provided 3?,Any ideas?

Comment: INSERT INTO [Data-People$] ([Fiscal Year], [Source], [Responsability]) VALUES (data1, data2, data3)

Comment: @User, please, pleaseeee edit your question and share your actual code. I don't see any parameter in this statement. It would simply give error.